# How to remove items for an ArrayList and updating the index of the element

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexing

I have an `ArrayList` that stores objects called `QuestionText`. This is the class for the objects below.

```
package me.bigbaddevil7.QnA;

public class QuestionText {
    int index;
    String username;
    String message;

    public QuestionText(int index, String username, String message){
        this.index = index;
        this.username = username;
        this.message = message;
    }


    public void setIndex(int i){
        index = i;
    }

    public void setUsername(String user){
        username = user;
    }

    public void setMessage(String msg){
        message = msg;
    }

    public int getIndex(){
        return index;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    public String getMessage(){
        return message;
    }
}
```

This issue that I am having as that all question objects will be stored in an ArrayList that can be accessed and manipulated later and I want the index to update properly.

So for example we added "Abby", "Bob", "Carl". With the corresponding indexes of 0,1,2. If I did a simple remove(1). Then it would be "Abby", "Carl" and the index that would be displayed is 0,2, and I would want 0,1. The index is displayed using the getIndex().

I looked at how Arrays handle removing an item and copying the array to a new one, but since this can happen many, many times, I didn't know if that would be the best approach to this issue.

Comment: Are you saying you want the original indexes to persist after you remove an item? If so, you can just `list.set(index, null);` and it will place a null value so that the elements to the right of the array don't shift.

Comment: I feel something wrong in the design itself when you are depending on the index of the collection in which you are storing it. I can be wrong but your code is too tightly integrated with the choice of its container. To answer your question, there is no way to do so without any hacking and I am not going to suggest that. Why does it has to depend on Index?

Comment: As far As i remember the ArrayList is already doing what you're asking for... You can test it

Answer (score 2):

You are approaching this problems as if the index were an attribute of the `QuestionText` class.  However, that is not the case.  Changing the order of the questions in the `ArrayList` shouldn't affect the `QuestionText` objects.  The index is a consequence of its position in the `ArrayList`; it's not an intrinsic part of the question.

I would completely remove the `index` variable and associated getter/setter from the `QuestionText` class.  The index depends on the `ArrayList` class instead.  Like an array, those indexes are fixed, starting with `0`.  Use the index into the `ArrayList` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to keep a record of it's index in your class? Can't you just call list.indexOf(QuestionText) whenever you need it? Since the index is susceptible to change it's not a great idea to store a value that's prone to change. Anytime you modify your list, you have to update the index of every element after the modified one.

To answer your question, i would change your setter to

```
public void setIndex(){
    index = list.indexOf(this);
}
```

You'll have to keep a reference to your list inside the class. Again, anytime you modify your list you have to call `setIndex` on all the elements after the modified element.

Another way, probably better, is to just keep your setter the way it is. However ANYTIME you modify your arraylist, you have to do something like this.

```
for(int i = (index of modified element);i<list.length();i++){
    list.get(i).setIndex(i);
}
```

If you're getting tired of me saying "anytime you modify...", then you're definitely going to be tired of calling this loop after every list modification, and inevitably, incorrect index values in your objects. I recommend rethinking your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using ArrayLists' method `remove(index)` already does this for you automatically. The items at position index + 1 to the end of the ArrayList will automatically shift down to fill the gap now created in the list. This is not true for arrays, however.

Additionally, unless there is a reason to store the index or position of an element in the ArrayList, you should remove the index variable. The ArrayList itself will take care of that for you.

Should there be a need to keep an instance variable holding the objects position in the ArrayList, you can always do the following:

Put the method `setIndex(index)` in the QuestionText class

```
public void setIndex(int index)
{
   this.index = index;
}
```

and iterate through the ArrayList and utilize the method to assign values to the variable

```
for (int i = 0; i < [list_name].size(); i++)
{
    [list_name].get(i).setIndex(i);
}
```